# RecyclerView Adapter Adds Duplicates TEXTVIEWs only on scroll

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView Adapter which adds data to RecyclerView, it works fine until I scroll up and down and see duplicate TextViews.

So my RecyclerView Loads like this

[image]

The issue is where you see `tag0` and `tag1` - If I scroll down and go back up, a duplicate set of `tag0` and `tag1` are added - as shown in the following screenshot

[image]

> It keeps happening over and over again everytime I scroll

My RecyclerView Adapter Code is the following (short version)

```
class VideoAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {       
        Context _context;
        private List<VideoDisplayModel> _AllLinks;

        public VideoAdapter(List<VideoDisplayModel> AllLinks)
        {
            _AllLinks = AllLinks;
        }


        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _AllLinks.Count;
            }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

 public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View listitem = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.VideoRecyclerRow, parent, false);
            TextView title = listitem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titleVideo);           
            ImageView image = listitem.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageVideo); 
            LinearLayout tagsLayout = listitem.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.tagsVideoLayout);

            VideoRecylerViewHolder view = new VideoRecylerViewHolder(listitem)
            {
                Title = title,              
                Thumb = image,                
                TagsLayout = tagsLayout
            };

            _context = parent.Context;
            return view;
        }


        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            var viewHolder = holder as VideoRecylerViewHolder;
            var currentLink = _AllLinks[position];
            viewHolder.Title.Text = currentLink.Title;


            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                TextView Txt = new TextView(_context);
                Txt.Text = "test"+i.ToString();
                Txt.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.roundtext);
                Txt.SetPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);   
 Txt.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#373944"));
                Txt.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 12);
                viewHolder.TagsLayout.AddView(Txt);
            }

        }
```

I don't understand, what am I doing wrong - Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: You add `viewHolder.TagsLayout.AddView(Txt);` but never remove.

Comment: You could just maintain the positions for which thew textViews are already added, and in the onBind add a check that add the text views only when they are not added before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RecyclerView recycles the same layout, so if you added a view before, it will add another one.. Make sure you clear the parent before adding the view:

```
viewHolder.TagsLayout.removeAllViews();  //THIS

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  ...
  viewHolder.TagsLayout.AddView(Txt);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand, what am I doing wrong - Any idea?

Yes, `OnBindViewHolder` gets called `multiple times` , its the basic fundamental of `recyclerView` , (**it recycles the views**).

> If you create views dynamically create and **add** views its gonna be called created multiple times once you `scroll` .

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    TextView Txt = new TextView(_context);
    Txt.Text = "test"+i.ToString();
    Txt.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.roundtext);
    Txt.SetPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);   
    Txt.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#373944"));
    Txt.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 12);
    viewHolder.TagsLayout.AddView(Txt);
 }
```

This loop is getting executed multiple times !!

So, before the for loop use :-

```
 holder.listitem.removeAllViews();
```